# Receive instant chatgpt response with typing text effect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, chatgpt-api

When you are using chatgpt browser extensions you receive chatgpt responses almost instantly by chunks with classic typing effect.

But when I used official chatgpt rest api. Responses come with much longer delay and with full answer.

As I understand this extensions do not use api they just grab the data directly from the website or iframe?
Is there any examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

- Use the `stream` variable in your object request.
- [Medium Article](https://betterprogramming.pub/openai-sse-sever-side-events-streaming-api-733b8ec32897)
- [Another Article](https://www.codingthesmartway.com/streaming-real-time-results-with-react-openai-and-server-sent-events/)
- [OpenAI docs on this.](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/fine-tunes/events#fine-tunes/events-stream)

## Sample request

```
{
    "messages": [
        //previous messages
    ],
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "stream": true,  
    "temperature": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stream` variable or get the full response and then use javascript to apply a typing effect. Something like this:

```
function typewriterEffect(text) {
let i = 0;
const delay = 100; // delay in milliseconds

function typeNextChar() {
if (i < text.length) {
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
i++;
setTimeout(typeNextChar, delay);
}
}

typeNextChar();
}
```

Usage:

```
const gptResponse = the variable where your API response is stored;
typewriterEffect(gptResponse);
```